# x-y coordinates & width-height of an image from sprite in html5

Tags: javascript, image, html, sprite

I have a sprite with many images.

Is there any method (maybe an app) by which I can get the x-y coordinates of an image from the sprite rather than guessing these parameters??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I made this one sometime back, very easy , mouse click and drag

[GetSpriteXY](https://getspritexy.netlify.com/)

[image]

Use Chrome or Firefox. Will not work in IE and Safari

Comment: Btw, that app uses HTML5 FileReader API

Comment: IE and Safari is also supported now.

Answer (score 1):

If you have made your sprite in photoshop or some other image editing software you can get the coordinates from that usually.  Alternatively you could use something like [SpriteCow!](http://www.spritecow.com/)

Comment: @kiranvj Not really too much of an issue.  If you are a web developer you hopefully have more than those two browsers installed but I understand you want to promote your own app.

Comment: Yes, I understand that, but its always good to have support in different browsers.